# Riemann integral with intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integration

Let $f(x) = \begin{cases} 3 && 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 0 && 1 \leq x  \leq 2 \end{cases}$

Compute $\displaystyle \ \ \int_0^2 f(x)dx\,\,\,$.

You can use the definition of Riemann integral to compute this where there is an $inf$ and a $sup$.

I was looking at this question and was wondering how would you prove this. I did not learn this but I want to know how this proof would look like. It seems really good to know.

From reading an article I came up with some of this which might help:

$P_n$ $=$ {$0$ , $1$-$({1/n})$, $1$+$({1/n})$, ...} where $n$ $=$ $2$, $3$, ...

I am just thinking what the proof should look like for fun. Can someone please show me? I would like to see the proof and then learn it.

This seems like a good place to learn it.

Comment: 1. $f(x)$ is not a function as it is not well-defined at $1$.
2. Is there any reason you want to use the definition rather than much easier theorem $\int_a^c f(x)\,dx = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx+\int_b^c f(x)\,dx$?

Comment: Why do you insist on tagging this general-topology, measure-theory, and lebesgue-integral? It's very misleading.

Comment: @genepeer Out of curiosity I wanted to see what the Riemann integral definition would look like to do the computation. I heard there is a way to use Riemann. Can I see the proof of that please? I would also like to see that easier theorem too if possible. I did not learn that one.

Comment: @genepeer Sorry. It was by accident.

Answer (score 1):

The Riemann integral is defined in the following way:

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\text{d}x = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i}^{*})\Delta x_{i}.$$

In the Riemann sum on the right-hand side $f(x_{i}^{*})$ is a sample point in the interval $(x_{i-1},x_{i})$ and $\Delta x_{i}$ is the width of that interval (which must go to zero as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for every $i$).

I'm going to partition the interval into $2^m$ equal sub-intervals and I will choose my sample points in the middle of each interval. Then:

$$\int_{0}^{2}f(x)\text{d}x = \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{2^{m}} f(x_{i}^{*})\frac{2}{2^{m}}$$
$$ = \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\left(\sum^{2^{m-1}}_{i=1}3\frac{2}{2^{m}} + \sum_{i=2^{m-1}+1}^{2^{m}}0\frac{2}{2^{m}} \right)$$
$$ = \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \left( 3 \times 2^{m-1} \times \frac{2}{2^{m}}\right) = 3$$
which is exactly what we would expect since the area under that graph is just the area of a rectangle with width $1$ and height $3$.